# List view tools are re-designing the view

Tags: list, view, tools

I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2013. I have a list with few items.
What I could not set currently, is a column width. There are many many forums in the internet with this topic, so I found a solution, which works for many users. Unfortunately I'm still not able to set a specified column width, but it is not working (I'm using Internet Explorer 10).

A required step was to enable the "List view tools", which was missing. I successfully enabled it, but after that the view generally modified. There is no quick edit function on the list anymore. And the "Add new" link was put to the bottom part.

I have two questions:
- **how can I restore** the original list with a toolbar? If I decide not to use the List View Tools...
- **what is a working solution** for modifying a column width in a sharepoint 2013 list

Answer (score 0):

On the list page, click edit and modify that page. Add script editor. Add to it custom CSS. Using F12 developer tools in IE or Chrome you can easily locate the right style that need to be amended so you get the right width of your column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping... Based on the answer from Marek Sarad a found an another article about this topic:

https://olafd.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/set-a-fixed-width-for-a-column-in-a-view/

Unfortunately this was still not working. But I checked the comments. And the post from Alison Anderson (19. June 2015 16:53) did what I was searching for.

```
$(“.ms-vh-div:contains(‘Comments’)”).css(“width”, “200px”)
```